# absolutely continuous measure -question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$\nu\ll\mu$ iff $|\nu|\ll\mu$ iff $\nu^{+}\ll\mu$ and $\nu^{-}\ll\mu$

Suppose $\nu\ll\mu$ and $\mu(E)=0$ (this if I understand follows from the hypothesis?) .

Let $X=P\cup N$ be the Hahn decomposition w.r.t $\nu$. let $\nu^{+}(E)=\nu(E\cap P)$ and $\nu^{-}(E)=-\nu(E\cap N)$

$\mu(E)=0\Rightarrow \mu(E\cap P)=0\Rightarrow \nu(E\cap P)=0$
similarly

$\mu(E)=0\Rightarrow \mu(E\cap N)=0\Rightarrow \nu(E\cap N)=0$

how do we know that?

We cannot use that $E\cap P\subseteq E$ and since $\mu(E)=0$ then $\mu(E\cap P)=0$ as we do not know if the measure is complete. What argument has been use in the above implications?

Comment: $\mu$ and $\nu$ are defined on the same $\sigma$-algebra, aren't they?

Comment: Yes they are both defined on $(X,\mathcal{M})$ one is signed the other is positive

Comment: So we have $E \in \mathcal{M}, P \in \mathcal{M}, N \in \mathcal{M}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer ah, does this mean that $E=\emptyset$? and $E\cap P=E\cap N=\emptyset$ and by definition their measures must be also zero.

Comment: We have $\mu(E\cap P) = 0$ since $\mu \geqslant 0$ and $E\cap P \subset E$ (similar for $N$). By absolute continuity, $\nu(E\cap P) = 0$.

Comment: but why is $\mu(E\cap P)=0$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10917/discussion-between-heidi-e-and-daniel-fischer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mu \geqslant 0$, every measurable subset $A$ of a $\mu$-null set $B$ is a $\mu$-null set, since

$$0 =\mu(B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B\setminus A) \geqslant \mu(A) \geqslant 0.$$

Thus, since $P$ and $N$ belong to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$, the two sets $E\cap P$ and $E\cap N$ are $\mu$-null sets whenever $E$ is one.

Comment: nice explanation, thank you for your help.